# Android upload using .apk and .obb files

Tags: android

I used to code Android apps full-time around 5 years ago. I'm now trying to get back to coding android as a hobby on the side.

I'm just grasping all the changes made, but I tried to upload a fresh build of my app/game using .apk and .obb files, but it seems I'm getting weird errors regarding TV compatibility asking me to upload them as a bundle .aab file.

Circling back to my question, is the only way to upload a working build for internal testing is to make an .aab bundle? Or is there a way to only upload .apk and .obb files?

Comment: The option to upload APKs for new apps was removed in 2021: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/new-android-app-bundle-and-target-api.html

Answer (score 0):

To release a build you have to upload bundle .aab on Google play store.

Here are steps to generate .aab file.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-signed-aab-file-in-android-studio/